# The importance of "Harichandra" for the human last funeral ceremony

Tags: rituals, death, cremation

In Hinduism, the people follow some process called "Harichandra" at the last time of human body in the cremation ground. And they also say some slogans at the time of the same.

Does anyone know about the things and any scriptures we are following in this kaliyuga?

Comment: Can you elaborate how this process is followed? Is the name Harichandra or Harishchandra? Where did you observe this process?

Comment: This is my personal incident saw before a few days... One of my relative expired due to aged and then he took to the `cementry` and there I saw  `cementry` employees having some sastra in front of the 3 feet stone called Harichandra and doing some process. I asked the people shared the thing is `the died person will request that please forgive me about if any lie i said in my life time` source said.

Comment: they buried his body?? Why not cremate?

Comment: Not buried they did cremated.

Comment: I think you should edit your question. Suggest changing 'burial ground' to 'cremation ground'. the present wording leads to confusion.

Comment: In Hindu scriptures there no separate burial and cremation grounds. They maintain only single.